# What is the Bluetooth revision supported by the 2015 Prius C?

Tags: toyota, bluetooth, prius

I am trying to find out what is the maximum Bluetooth protocol level that the 2015 Prius C will **use** (if it matters, I have the "Two" trim, without the Entune system). I understand that Bluetooth devices are backwards-compatible; I know that if I have, say, a Bluetooth 4.1 device, then it'll still work even if the car only supports Bluetooth 2.0 -- but in that case, both the client and the receiver will speak Bluetooth 2.0 to each other, since they fall back to the lowest common denominator. I am looking for the maximum protocol level that the car will actually "speak".

Page 322 of the 2015 Toyota Prius C Manual (part # OM52E68U) states:

> Ver. 2.0 or higher (Recommended: Ver. 3.0+EDR or higher)

This is the only information I could find that even *suggests* the maximum version of the Bluetooth spec that the Prius C actually supports -- it seems to suggest that 3.0 + EDR is supported. However, it doesn't actually come out and say that it supports 3.0.

I am mostly interested in seeing if it actually supports things like:

- Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy (LE)
- apt-X or AAC audio codecs

However, the manual doesn't state it, so I'm left to either assume that it doesn't support them, or maybe it does and the manual writers didn't get the memo.

Comment: I'd recommend going to a dealership and testing it.  If they think you're interested in the car they'll be more than happy to let you test.  What is the need you have for 4.0 support?  Just audio quality and battery savings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about connecting your iPhone which uses the "LE" to do things like air drop etc, you should be fine, your 4.0 system is backwards compatible. You are right it will only connect at the "highest" speed of the slowest device. Called my friend at the dealer and asked for you about the audio formats. It should play fine based off of your device as its just playing the audio through the bluetooth and not taking the song from your device then decoding it through the deck to your ears. Hope that clears it up. Let me know if my friend is wrong.